# Creating Outlook Application Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object, reference, outlook, instance

Hello I am creating a new Outlook.Application (with v.14.0.0.0 Office library) and retrieving the inbox email with C#. Only when outlook is not running, I am getting the error

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

in a alert(Occurred by the first line). The program is runnig ahead(doesn't even go in the catch part).

```
try {
    Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    foreach (Object obj in folder.Items) {
        if (obj is Outlook.MailItem) {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)obj;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately an error occurred");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Is there any solution for this annoying alert? Can I suppress it or fix the problem?

The alert is coming from a Outlook instance, I can see it because in the navigation bar a outlook instance is open (the little alert dialog).

Comment: Does `folder` object has _items_? Looks like you created an object but not to initialize it. Did you debug your code line by line?

Comment: Yes folder has items, 131.

Comment: What line is it crashing?

Comment: Which line gives you this error ? Debug it.

Comment: The first line. 
Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();

It doens't crash its just giving a alert and running ahead.

Comment: [`Outlook.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application(v=office.14).aspx) isn't an _interface_?

Comment: It is a interface. `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: @Niklas I tried your code in my Visual Studio but it doesn't gave me any error. Are you sure about your error created by your first line?

Comment: Yes I am sure. But maybe its a problem on my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to first try and get a reference to the running instance, and only create a new one (`new Outlook.Application()`) if an existing instance can't be attached to.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097%28v=office.14%29.aspx) makes it pretty clear.

Shameless rip directly from MSDN article:

```
Outlook.Application application = null;

// Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
{

    // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
    application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
}
else
{

    // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
    application = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    nameSpace = null;
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine, but it doesn't fix that problem about the alert dialog.

Comment: This sounds more like something is amiss with your Outlook configuration. Maybe an add-in?

Comment: If I am executing this code twice, I am getting an error and jumping into the catch block.

`Operation unavailable <Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 <MK_E_UNAVAILABLE>>`

on line

`outlookApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;`

Must I exit/quit/terminate the application at the end of the program?

Comment: Outlook is a singleton, so you can always create a new instance of Outlook.Application - you will get back the running instance if outlook.exe is already running.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but unfortunately this answer doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the message

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

was thrown by the Snag-it plugin. So this has nothing to do with the core Outlook.

I disabled the Plugin and I no longer got this message.